# Getting active scaffold to work without :mark action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

I'm currently working on a project using Rails 3.2 and Active Scaffold.  I've created a simple controller for one of my models that is coded thusly:

```
  class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  active_scaffold :student do |conf|
    conf.label = "Students"
    conf.columns = [:last_name, :first_name, :age, :gender, :grade_level, :current_grade]
    conf.create.columns = [:last_name, :first_name, :age, :gender, :grade_level]
    conf.update.columns = [:last_name, :first_name, :age, :gender, :grade_level]
    conf.columns[:current_grade].actions_for_association_links = [:show]
    conf.columns[:current_grade].sort_by :sql => "grade_level"
    conf.actions = [:list, :search, :create, :update, :show, :delete]
    list.columns.exclude :customer_id, :grade_level
    list.sorting = {:last_name => 'ASC'}
  end

  def conditions_for_collection
    ["customer_id = #{current_user.customer_id}"]
  end

  def before_create_save(record)
    record.customer_id = current_user.customer_id

  end
end
```

My problem is this:  When I delete a record, I receive a message that states '$record_name can't be deleted'.  Yet I find the record is in fact deleted if I refresh the page.  Upon examining my log file I see an error message stating:

```
undefined method `as_marked=' for #<Student:0x0000000554c1d0>
```

I tried adding :mark to my list of actions and that does solve the problem.  However, I don't want a mark/checkbox column to show up in my list.

Any ideas?  This is my first time using active scaffold, and I find this... annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that if I add this to my model:

```
  def as_marked= (x)
  end
```

it works, without showing a mark/checkbox column in my list.

For the record, I hate this solution :)  If I come up with anything better I'll make sure to come back and update this answer.